# Is there an app that allows users to create a map from an image?

Tags: applications

I come from Android and one of the little apps I used to use that was very handy was [Custom Maps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.custommapsapp.android).

It allows you to create a map from any image by selecting a few points on the image and defining their location.

Is there an app in the App store that allows this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TomTom calls this feature [Map Overlays](http://create.tomtom.com/manuals/create-your-own-content/index.html?map_overlays.htm), but their [iPhone app](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tomtom-u.s.-canada/id326075661?mt=8) doesn't support it.

Garmin calls this feature [Custom Maps](http://www.garmin.com/us/products/onthetrail/custommaps), but their [iPhone app](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/garmin-u.s.a./id435490305?mt=8) doesn't support it either.

The only app I found that supports this feature is [MakkaMappa](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/makkamappa-gps-any-map-to/id395677665?mt=8) ($1, or free [lite version](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/makkamappa-lite-gps-any-map/id437017607?mt=8)). Basically you upload an image to their website, then you use this application to view the map with your location shown on it.

From the app description:

> Once you've uploaded your map to the website, use this app to view the map on your iPhone. Even better, go to the location the map represents, and view it there. You'll be amazed when you see your position correctly shown on the map, no matter how much the map is stretched or squashed compared to the geographic space it represents. You won't need a data connection to view maps – great if you're going abroad.

[image]

Comment: I'd upvote this answer if they'd let me :)